# What happened to the Re:Zero manga?

Tags: re-zero

I was hoping that I could read the continuation of the series through the manga, but I can't find any chapter beyond 23, it has been like that for a long time. Is the manga on hiatus or something?

Also, yes I know about https://translationchicken.com/ but I heard that the web novel was kinda trash compared to the light novel, so I refrained from reading the translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Re:Zero has* been licensed by Yen Press officially in English and currently (27/07/2017) they have done [both](http://www.hachettebookgroup.com/titles/tappei-nagatsuki/rezero-starting-life-in-another-world-vol-1-manga/9780316315319/?yen) [volumes](http://www.hachettebookgroup.com/titles/tappei-nagatsuki/rezero-starting-life-in-another-world-vol-2-manga/9780316398541/?yen) of *Chapter 1: A Day in the Capital* and the [first volume](http://www.hachettebookgroup.com/titles/tappei-nagatsuki/rezero-starting-life-in-another-world-chapter-2-a-week-at-the-mansion-vol-1-manga/9780316471886/?yen) of *Chapter 2: A Week at the Mansion*

according [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Re:Zero_%E2%88%92_Starting_Life_in_Another_World_volumes#Manga) the next volume of Chapter 2 of the Manga is expected to be released on August 22, 2017 with Chapter 2 being fully done by the end of the year while *Chapter 3: Truth of Zero* is expected to start being released at the end of October, 2017 with Volume 3 of it expected in April, 2018.

[image: wikipedia quote screenshot]

as you can see from the link and screenshot the japanese release of Volume 5 of Chapter 3 was in March 2017 but previous volumes have been between a few months apart. however it is based off the Light Novel which is still ongoing with the last release being Volume 13 released in June 2017 (and also licensed by Yen Press and have planned up to Volume 5 currently (27/07/2017))

So no, there doesn't seem to be a hiatus but rather Yen Press taking their time, probably a good thing because you wouldn't want this stuff rushed

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late and you probably already found an answer. The LN is based off the WN, just edited. The WN is the rough draft for the LN. The manga just follows the anime and I'm not sure if it covers anything after(might need clarification on this part).

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re:Zero_%E2%88%92_Starting_Life_in_Another_World#Light_novel

The Wikipedia page has information about the editing of the Light Novel from the Web Novel.
There are the original sources at the bottom of the Wikipedia page. 
The manga part was by word of mouth and I have not officially read the Manga. Only the LN and the WN.